# Any way to extract XML into constants in Scala?

Tags: xml, scala

Beginner to Scala here coming from a Java background. Suppose I have a bunch of XML just floating around in my code:

```
val x = <file> <name> some-file.txt </name> </file>
```

Is there any way I can extract the XML elements into named constants? I've tried the following, but it doesn't work as on the first line it's still expecting a closing `</file>` tag:

```
val FileStart = <file>
val FileEnd = </file>
```

I ask because I want to avoid magic values floating around in my code. I cringe at the thought of using the `<name>` tag 100 times and then having its value change ten months down the road (which would result in a terrible tag hunt). I'd much rather have it defined in a constant somewhere.

Better yet, is there a Scala way to efficiently approach this problem? Maybe I'm stuck in Java thinking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your suggestion is not a good one, as the following:

```
val FileStart = <file>
val FileEnd = </file>
```

doesn't create and assign to a variable a valid XML nodes, which is required and validated during compilation. Even more unexpectedly Scala compiler will interpret the above as definition of a single node FileStart, as a `<file>val FileEnd = </file>` XML node ;)

Since you're worried of having multiple `name` tags for which you might need to change the node name, I'd rather suggest defining a set of separate reusable methods i.e.:

```
def nameNode(name : String) = <name>{name}</name>

def fileNode(name : String) = <file>{nameNode(name)}</file>

def createXml(files : List[String]) = <myLovelyFiles>
  {files.map(fileNode)}
</myLovelyFiles>
```

This way you will not only avoid duplicating tag name 100 times, but also should you need to test some complex functionality when constructing XML you've got a small testable units for it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Extraction:

```
scala> val x = <file> <name> some-file.txt </name> </file>
x: scala.xml.Elem = <file> <name> some-file.txt </name> </file>

scala> import xml.Elem
import xml.Elem

scala> x match { case Elem(prefix, label, attrs, ns, children @ _*) => println(label) }
file

scala> val File = "file"
File: String = file

scala> x match { case Elem(prefix, File, attrs, ns, children @ _*) => println(children) } 
ArrayBuffer( , <name> some-file.txt </name>,  )

scala> x match { case Elem(prefix, File, attrs, ns, children @ _*) => children \\ "name" }
res4: scala.xml.NodeSeq = NodeSeq(<name> some-file.txt </name>)
```

`File` must not start with a lower-case letter, otherwise it is a variable.

Well, that's if you're extracting nodes without using literal tags in the pattern.

If you want to construct nodes without using literals, you can do that, too:

```
scala> val n = <name> some-file.txt </name>
n: scala.xml.Elem = <name> some-file.txt </name>

scala> val file = "file"
file: String = file

scala> import xml._
import xml._

scala> val f = Elem(null, file, Null, TopScope, minimizeEmpty = false, n)
f: scala.xml.Elem = <file><name> some-file.txt </name></file>
```

Here is a nice syntax:

https://github.com/lihaoyi/scalatags#hello-world

That focuses on producing html text.

```
scala> val tag = "file"
tag: String = file

scala> val file: Node => Node = Elem(null, tag, Null, TopScope, true, _)
file: scala.xml.Node => scala.xml.Node = <function1>

scala> file { <name> some-file.txt </name> }
res0: scala.xml.Node = <file><name> some-file.txt </name></file>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly! As a Scala beginner I don't know what this code does: could you explain it to me? I don't see how this solves the problem.

Comment: @dylanlknowles I must have read your question quickly. I thought you wanted to extract xml without using constant tags.

Comment: Yeah, I was a little confused to say the least! I saw case matching and didn't think it applied to my problem, but being a noob I thought I was just mistaken; I'm happy to know my understanding of Scala isn't fundamentally wrong. Thanks for taking the time to edit your answer!